# Notice for questions with previous bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I couldn't find this topic discussed on here.

> Is it a good idea to have a visual cue on questions with an expiried un-awarded bounty?

If you're providing an answer someone really wanted at some point in time, it would be good to see an icon or something like that in the question to indicate that.

Sure you "star" a favourite question to be alerted to new answers, just thinking when answering a question if there was a flag you might delve a bit deeper in your answer if you knew it had a bounty on it at some point in time.

[image]

Comment: *Most* users will only go that extra mile if the bounty is still active. Your suggestion may be good for users like yourself who would go the extra mile on expired bounties, but mostly bounties work well & attract attention at the time. If they don't, perhaps the question is unanswerable, or not enough people could answer it, etc. In either case the *active* bounty weight is higher than *expired* bounty weight, so if *active* bounty failed to bring answers how affective would expired bounty notifications be? Adding another bounty is the best method if users really want an answer.